# How I change the size of bubbles in google charts?

Tags: javascript, html, web, google-visualization, pygooglechart

I create a bubble chart using google-charts. It seems like this:
[image]

Here the data that i use:

[image]

My Question is How I change the size of bubbles so they will be like the column:"bubble size" that in the table?
And how can i make the X-axis be more wider?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/bubblechart#data-format), it seems the 5th column should control the size of the bubble. And the 4th should be an ID (I'd use the country's code for this, or just repeat the counytry col again).